Maven: Change deploy directory of /src/main/resources
In a dynamic project in Eclipse I would like the files under /src/main/resource to be deployed in a directory other than WEB-INF/classes (specifically I would like to deploy them in WEB-INF/cfg).
I tried to change, in Java Build Path, the "Output folder" with target/cfg and the "Deploy Path" under Deploy Assembly but when I run Maven clean + Maven Install, the files under /src/main/resource continue to be deployed under WEB-INF/classes




Update
This is my pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebAppTest</artifactId>
    <version>01</version>
    <name>WebAppTest</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes></packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <!-- dependencies -->
</project>


Maven is not aware of the Java Build Path. So do not change Java Build Path, but your pom.xml.

Do you want to do something like that?

Can you please add your pom.xml so we could figure out what's going on? (And please use a [mre] for that)

Why do you need that cfg part?

@howlger could you kindly tell me how to change the pom? I added my current pom in the question

use src/main/webapp and place them in WEB-INF/cfg inside that folder if that is where they need to be./

@cyberbrain I think the case is reproducible with the information I entered in the question (the pom that I have now added was missing). Is there anything else missing?

Use src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/cfg instead. The Maven WAR plugin knows all about the src/main/webapp folder, and uses it as the root of the WAR. But you probably already know that, sine you already have a src/main/webapp folder.

I tried renaming my source folder to src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/cfg but the files are deployed under both WEB-INF/cfg and WEB-INF/classes. Did you mean something different?

@Charles did you perform a clean after renaming the folder? Maven doesn't remove anything that's already in target/classes unless you tell it to, and that content goes to WEB-INF/classes. I've had the same issue before where moved or removed files kept being used. That got resolved when I ran mvn clean package instead of just mvn package.

You are right. The strange thing is that with mvn clean install it works correctly while by running mvn clean first and then mvn install I have the problem... however with your suggestion I solved it. To be honest I don't really like the fact of having a source folder called src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/cfg, I was hoping to solve it with some configuration in the pom leaving the name of the folder as per convention, but your solution works, thanks

You're welcome.
